How to Prevent NaN Values from Affecting Attention in a PyTorch TransformerEncoder
I'm working on a Transformer-based encoder model using PyTorch. I want the model to ignore certain values in the sequence that are marked as NaN and ensure these NaN values do not affect the rest of the sequence. I'm trying to implement a mask to achieve this, but the results are not as expected. Here is my test code:
import torch as th
from torch import nn

B, S, C = 3, 5, 1
hidden_size = 3
num_heads = 1
num_encoder_layers = 1

# Layers
linear = nn.Linear(C, hidden_size)
encoder = nn.TransformerEncoder(
    nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(
        d_model=hidden_size,
        nhead=num_heads,
        batch_first=True,
        activation=nn.ReLU(),
    ),
    num_layers=num_encoder_layers,
    norm=nn.LayerNorm(hidden_size),
)

x = th.rand(B, S, C)
x[0, 2, :] = th.nan
x[2, 4, :] = th.nan

# Mask for lookahead
tri_mask = th.full((S, S), 1)
tri_mask = th.tril(tri_mask, diagonal=1) == 0

x = linear(x)
nan_mask = th.isnan(x).any(dim=-1)
valid_mask = ~nan_mask
attn_mask = valid_mask.unsqueeze(1) & valid_mask.unsqueeze(2)
x_out = encoder(x, mask=attn_mask)

print("Output:\n", x_out)
print("Attention Mask:\n", attn_mask)

My goal is to ensure that the model ignores the NaN values in the sequence so that they do not affect the attention mechanism of the Transformer. However, the output is not as expected. Specifically, the values NaN in x[0, 2, :] and x[2, 4, :] seem to propagate through the model.
The current output of the code is:
tensor([[[nan, nan, nan],
         [nan, nan, nan],
         [nan, nan, nan],
         [nan, nan, nan],
         [nan, nan, nan]],

        [[nan, nan, nan],
         [nan, nan, nan],
         [nan, nan, nan],
         [nan, nan, nan],
         [nan, nan, nan]],

        [[nan, nan, nan],
         [nan, nan, nan],
         [nan, nan, nan],
         [nan, nan, nan],
         [nan, nan, nan]]], grad_fn=<NativeLayerNormBackward0>)

The attention mask being used is:
tensor([[[ True,  True, False,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True, False,  True,  True],
         [False, False, False, False, False],
         [ True,  True, False,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True, False,  True,  True]],

        [[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]],

        [[ True,  True,  True,  True, False],
         [ True,  True,  True,  True, False],
         [ True,  True,  True,  True, False],
         [ True,  True,  True,  True, False],
         [False, False, False, False, False]]])

Once the problem is solved, I would like to combine that mask of valid records with the triangular mask with lookahead that is listed as tri_mask because I would like each record to only be able to see the one next to itself in the sequence and all the previous ones.
Is there any way to do this?
